# The system cannot find the path specified (Pyspark/Pycharm)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm, environment-variables

I'm facing an issue while executing Pyspark codes from both command prompt or Pycharm.  I had pip installed spark/Pyspark, but I'm still unable to reach spark from any terminal

> Error: The system cannot find the path specified

Environmental variables are set as per requirements, but still, the issue is persisting.

For the below simple pyspark code, I am getting the error from pycharm.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Session1').getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv("C:/Users/1875977/Desktop/clustering_mindset_jan.csv")
df.printSchema()
```

Note: Softwares installed are Anaconda(Python 3.7), Windows OS, Hadoop Utils, Java 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Check the tutorial [[here]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html)

```
spark.read.load("C:/Users/1875977/Desktop/clustering_mindset_jan.csv",
                         format="csv")
```

Example :

[image]